# Como acessar uma imagem que foi para pasta uploads do meu laravel através do FIleUpload

Tags: html, angularjs, laravel

Eu tenho um `form` que faz `uploads` de imagens , quando eu faço o upload , o caminho fica gravado no banco pelo campo `path` , eu recupero do banco essa imagem e jogo num `array` `image`

```
this.image = data;
```

agora como posso exibir essa imagem em um `HTML` usando o 
`image.path` ??

```
<img src="{{ image.path }}">
```

tentei isso e não deu certo

Código do meu controller de imagens

```js
$filename = $file->store("uploads/{$idCampaign}/images");
                if (!$agency) { throw new NotFoundHttpException('agency_not_found'); }
                if ($filename) {
                    $image->file_extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $image->filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->path = $filename;
                    $result = $this->service->save($image);

                    $img = new ImageCampaign();
                    $img->setCampaign($campaign);
                    $img->setImage($image);
                    $img->setAgency($agency);
                    $img->fill($request->post());


                    $this->imageCampaignService->save($img);

                    DB::commit();
                    return response()->json($result);
```

este código insere a imagem no banco

Comment: se pode colocar todo o código utilizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da uma olhada na documentação oficial:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-urls

Mas quando você faz um upload ele joga o arquivo na pasta storage, porém somente a pasta public é visível publicamente, sendo assim o que o Laravel indica fazer é criar uma pasta public/storage e criar um link simbólico com a pasta storage/app/public. Dessa forma arquivos que forem colocados no storage/app/public poderão ser vistos publicamente.

Para exibir fica facil:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$image_name}}">
```

Comment: Vou tentar isso mas ainda não entendi como fazer um link simbólico

Comment: Ainda conforme a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk

Basta executar:
php artisan storage:link